# Are these partial derivatives done correctly? Is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ if $f(x,y) = (x^2 +y^2)\text{log}(x^2+y^2)$.

Ok, to my understanding, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ will just be the derivative keeping all terms besides $x$ fixed.

I use the logarithm base-change law: $\text{log}(x^2+y^2) = \frac{\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)}{\text{ln}(10)}$.

Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{(2x+y^2)\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)}{\text{ln}(10)} + \frac{1}{\text{ln}(10)}(\frac{2x+y^2}{x^2+y^2})(x^2+y^2) = \frac{2x+y^2}{\text{ln}(10)}[\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)+1]$.

Similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{2y+x^2}{\text{ln}(10)}[\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)+1]$. Please tell me if I did this correctly.

My *real* question is if $f$ is differentiable, which is not required for my homework, but I am curious about this case. At $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the partials are discontinuous. A theorem in my book states:

*Let $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose the partial derivatives $\partial f_i / \partial x_j$ of $f$ all exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of a point $\textbf x \in U$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $\textbf x$.*

If the partials of $f$ are discontinuous at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, does this imply that $f$ is not differentiable as a whole? If we state the condition $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, does $f$ become differentiable? Please explain (preferably in terms of neighborhoods).

Comment: First, $f(0,0)= 0$? Second, you can have $f$ differentiable with discontinuous partials. Special reasoning (definition of $\partial$) is required at (0,0).

Comment: I think that in the statement of the problem $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm, so that there is no "base change" necessary.

Comment: This puzzles me, how do you know that question means the natural logarithm? Why wouldn't the authors just write ln($x^2+y^2$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that your derivatives are wrong.

They should be  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{2 x \left(\log \left(x^2+y^2\right)+1\right)}{\log (10)}$$ and  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2 y \left(\log \left(x^2+y^2\right)+1\right)}{\log (10)}$$ I hope this will allow you to continue.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. When I read about the partial derivative I didn't realize "fixed" meant "constant", so obviously $y^2$ gets eliminated with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$...

Answer (score 0):

In your example $f$ is not defined in $(0, 0)$ and thus it is not differentiable in $(0, 0)$.

Comment: A function  might be undefined at a point but still extend differentiably to this point. For example $\sin(x)/x$. But not in the our case though.

Comment: @GilBor It is still not differentiable, by definition you need $f(x)$ to be defined for $f$ to be differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Correct, but when a function is not defined at some point,  we me be able, sometimes,  to extend its definition in a differentiable manner. For example, the formula  $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ does  not define $f$  at  $x=0$, but by defining  $f(0)=1$ the new function is differentiable at $x=0$. This may or may not be possible to do for a given function undefined at a point. It turns out that for the function given by the OP it is impoosible to extend it diffrentiably (or even continiously) to $(0,0)$.